# hit detect canvas JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, canvas

i want to detect clicks on canvas elements which are drawn using paths. so far i have think of to store elements path in javascript data structure and then check the cordinates of hits which matches the elements cordinates. i belive there is algorithm already for thins kind o cordinate search. rendering each of element path and checking the hits would be inefficient when elements number is larger. can anyone point on me that?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript canvas context has an isPointInPath method.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_ispointinpath.asp

If you'd like to implement your own Point In Polygon algorithm check out the Wikipedia page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Point_in_polygon_queries

Comment: yes i know that function. if i have many elements, i dont want to check each of them with that method as it will slow things down.i had planed to store cordinates and path of element in js data structure. the problem is how to sort among those elements which tend be more around the point user clicked. i was looking for that algorithm if any is there.

Comment: @user1538127 - If you're looking for an optimization, you may want to consider, bound-box or bounding-circle as a first stage in your hit detection. Create a bounding-circle around each path and do a fast distance-to-point vs radius comparison, then only if its a hit on the circle, do the more expensive point-in-polygon detection.

Comment: how can i calculate bounding box of polygon? can you give some reference?

Comment: @user1538127 - The rotating calipers algorithm will find you the minimum bounding box (assuming your paths are convex). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers

Comment: i have looked int that after reading your comments and googled and read the resources but still having hard time to understand how to implement it. can you give link to any good illustrated resource about it? and what about concave polygons?

Answer (score 0):

There are quit a few libraries that are j=doing just that such as:

paper.js http://paperjs.org/

fabric.js http://fabricjs.com/

kenetic.js http://kineticjs.com/

I sugget you either check the code base or build on top of these.

Comment: i just want to give it a try myself. it is for educational purpose. other than libraries any pointers on solving the problem would be great. thanks for your reply though.